# How to send email in tabular format using shell script

Tags: html, bash, shell, email, hdfs

================

```
current mail output
HDFS_SPACE: 255.7 G /grv/mall/;
 S3_SPACE: Total Size: 255.7 GiB
```

=====
Table format mail output is required with 3 rows
1st row header title --CURRENT SPACE
2ND ROW WILL HAVE 2 COLUMN with header HDFS_SPACE and S3_SPACE WITH output as /grv/mall 255.7 G and  Total Size: 255.7 GiB

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?